# Have there been any "breaking changes" in the history of Unicode?

Tags: unicode

As Unicode versions progress, has there ever been a breaking change? For example, has it ever occurred that a symbol's code point has been re-mapped, be it so that this symbol appears together with the ones it relates to (think of a character set for a language that at some point gained a new letter)?

May Unicode "change" these things at all, or is there a guarantee that these mappings are constant forever?

If there weren't any code point re-mappings, have there been other breaking changes?

Comment: Unicode has a [stability policy](http://www.unicode.org/policies/stability_policy.html). Policy #1: "Once a character is encoded, it will not be moved or removed." Here is [a survey of changes](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/03/12/394716.html).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, your comment answers my question. Would you be willing to transform it into an answer so I can choose it?

Comment: http://unicode.org/errata/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there have been many breaking changes. One interesting story related by Michael Kaplan (late Microsoft internationalization expert) in an [archived version of "Every character has a story #5"](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/01/29/363208.html), quotes Ken Whistler:

> Hundreds -- maybe thousands -- of Unicode 1.0 character names were changed in 1993 for Unicode 1.1 as part of the merger between the repertoires of Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646-1:1993. (The Great Compromise) The gory details of all the changes can be found in UTR #4, The Unicode Standard, Version 1.1. It was *after* that point (which was *very* painful for some people) that we put in place the never change a character name rule.

In another post (["Stability of the Unicode Character Database", archived](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/03/12/394716.html)), Kaplan quotes a discussion of changes to character categories, with this quote also by Ken Whistler:

> The significant point of instability in General Category assignments was in establishing Unicode 2.0 data files (now more than 8 years in the past).
>
> There was a significant hiccup for Unicode 3.0, at the point when it became clear that normalization stability was going to be a major issue, and when the data was culled for consistency under canonical and compatibility equivalence.
>
> Since that time, the UTC has been very conservative, indeed, in approving any General Category change for an existing character. The types of changes have been limited to:
>
> 1. Clarification regarding obscure characters for which insufficient information was available earlier.
> 2. Establishment of further data consistency constraints (this impacted some numeric categories, and also explains the change for the Katakana middle dot)
> 3. Implementation issues with a few format characters (ZWSP, Arabic end of ayah, Mongolian free variation selectors)

There were many changes early in Unicode, and fewer "breaking changes" as time went on. **Unicode has an official [Stability Policy](http://www.unicode.org/policies/stability_policy.html)**, describing what changes are no longer allowed, and the "applicable version" at which they instituted each policy (and thus finished making that kind of change). I have to expect that each of those policies may tell a story of changes being made, causing all sorts of trouble for people who were relying on the prior behavior and needing to update existing data in some way, or at least people knew that more pain would come in the future if they didn't fix those particular aspects of Unicode at that time. It really makes some amount of sense that as Unicode got adopted problems with particular aspects were found and fixed, and now that Unicode is ubiquitous there is less need to make breaking changes and more need to keep compatibility with the existing data that's out there.

To answer your specific question about code point placement, let me quote the Encoding Stability Policy:

> ### Encoding Stability
>
> **Applicable Version: Unicode 2.0+**
>
> **Once a character is encoded, it will not be moved or removed.**
>
> This policy ensures that implementers can always depend on each version of the Unicode Standard being a superset of the previous version. The Unicode Standard may deprecate the character (that is, formally discourage its use), but it will not reallocate, remove, or reassign the character.
>
> ***Note:*** Ordering of characters is handled via collation, not by moving characters to different code points. For more information, see Unicode Technical Standard #10, Unicode Collation Algorithm, and the Unicode FAQ.

In general, I expect that you can rely on the Unicode Consortium to keep the promises that they've now made in their Stability Policy, though you may need to be aware of the changes made before each policy existed if you have data that predates the adoption of that applicable version of Unicode by the software that created it. And data not explicitly called out as now being "stable" can of course be changed in any future version.